# CLI interactive merge tool

Tags: command-line, plain-text, file-merging

I'm looking for a CLI (or more accurately TUI), interactive merge tool that can work on any arbitrary pair of files.

Ideally it would have a UX similar to `git add --patch` - diff the files, chunk the diff, and then ask which version you want to use.

It should work on any two arbitrary text files, even outside of a git repo. So for example `merge-tool a b > c` would show interactive prompts similar to what you would see if `a` was the base file, `b` was the unstaged local changeset, and c is where the resulting file will be written.